# Trouble proving or giving a counterexample

Tags: logic

So I can see why these statements would be true or false. I'm just having trouble to prove *why*. For example:

> if $\alpha \vDash \gamma$ or $\beta \vDash \gamma$ then $(\alpha \wedge \beta) \vDash \gamma$

I know this is true, as it as obvious in my mind. But how would I best prove this?

Or

> if $(\alpha \wedge \beta) \vDash \gamma$ then $\alpha \vDash \gamma$ or $ \beta \vDash \gamma$

This one would be false. But how would I deliver a counterexample?

Comment: What is your the definition of $\models$? I think the proof of former question depends on the definition.

Comment: If you take $\beta = \lnot\alpha$ and $\gamma = \bot$, you may get a counterexample of the second question.

Comment: A different counterexample for the second one would be to take $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be different propositional variables, and $\gamma$ to be $\alpha\land\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\delta\models\xi\,$ *iff* $\,\models \delta\to\xi$, so by hypothesis $\models\alpha\to\gamma$ or $\models\beta\to\gamma$. If $M$ is a model such that $M\models \alpha\land\beta$, then $M\models\alpha$ and $M\models\beta$. Because $M\models\alpha\to\gamma$ or $M\models\beta\to\gamma$, in either case we have $M\models\gamma$.

The comments by Hanul and Henning provide good counterexamples to the second claim.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the first statement, first take the $\gamma$ to the left by adding implication. This makes the expression,
$$ \alpha \to \gamma \lor \beta \to \gamma $$
Assume $ \alpha \land \beta $

Divide into 2 boxes with $\alpha \to \gamma $ and $\beta \to \gamma $.

Assume $\sim \gamma$,

By Modus Tollens , you get $\sim \alpha$ , a contradiction.
and similarly  for $\beta$.

Hence $\gamma$.

Comment: This seems to speak about formal proofs (which would be the right thing to speak about if the question had said $\vdash$), but since the question says $\vDash$ it want an argument phrased in terms of _semantics_.

Comment: I thought that as natural logic is sound, a formal proof would imply semantic entailment .